#  mapping table fields with grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a business requirement where I need to map several pair of tables based on pre-defined set of rules.  The tables contain the same data but have different schemas. For example: field `name` in table `abc` is same as field `fullname` in table `def`. My business requirement needs me to map several tables like that. I thought of using grails 'DRY' principle.

To try out with an example, I created two domain classes `Abc` and `Def` in Grails and a third class called `AbcDefMapping`. Then in Controller template I created a method called `convert` where I split `AbcDefMapping` string into `Abc`, `Def` and `Mapping` strings. Now I want to call method `Abc.list()` in my generated controller. How do I do that? (Edit: I solved this one, please look at my other question i.e. if there is a better way to do this)

This is my code:

```
  def convert(){

    def cn = "${className}"

    def lis = []
    def str = ""
    for (i in cn){

        if (i == i.toUpperCase() && str!=""){
            lis.add(str)
            str = i
        }
        else{

            str = str +i
        }
    }
    lis.add(str)

    def inputs = \${lis[0]}.list() // lis[0] = "Abc"
}
```

I want the inputs to go as `Abc.list()` in the generated code.

Otherwise, could you please tell me a better way of achieving what I want to do here?

Comment: ok, I found the solution. ${className.substring(0,3)}.list() will give me my desired result. Now I can compute the location of uppercases and use it. My second question is still valid though i.e. is there a better way to do this.

Comment: you should edit your question just to reflect what you are looking for so other users won't get confused and give you answers for what you already got by yourself.